# Failed to run a python job in a EMR spark cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to submit a python job to a AWS EMR spark cluster.

My setting in the spark-submit options section is as following:

--master yarn --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g

However, I encountered a failed case during the job running.

The following is the error log file:

```
19/04/09 10:40:25 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal/172.31.53.241:8032
19/04/09 10:40:26 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 3 NodeManagers
19/04/09 10:40:26 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (11520 MB per container)
19/04/09 10:40:26 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 4505 MB memory including 409 MB overhead
19/04/09 10:40:26 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
19/04/09 10:40:26 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
19/04/09 10:40:26 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
19/04/09 10:40:26 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
19/04/09 10:40:29 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-a8e941b7-f20f-46e5-8b2d-05c52785bd22/__spark_libs__3200812915608084660.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1554806206610_0001/__spark_libs__3200812915608084660.zip
19/04/09 10:40:32 INFO Client: Uploading resource s3://spark-yaowen/labelp.py -> hdfs://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1554806206610_0001/labelp.py
19/04/09 10:40:32 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://spark-yaowen/labelp.py' for reading
19/04/09 10:40:32 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1554806206610_0001/pyspark.zip
19/04/09 10:40:33 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1554806206610_0001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip
19/04/09 10:40:34 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-a8e941b7-f20f-46e5-8b2d-05c52785bd22/__spark_conf__6746542371431989978.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1554806206610_0001/__spark_conf__.zip
19/04/09 10:40:34 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
19/04/09 10:40:34 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
19/04/09 10:40:34 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/04/09 10:40:34 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/04/09 10:40:34 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/04/09 10:40:36 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1554806206610_0001 to ResourceManager
19/04/09 10:40:37 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1554806206610_0001
19/04/09 10:40:38 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:38 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1554806436561
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1554806206610_0001/
     user: hadoop
19/04/09 10:40:39 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:40 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:41 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:42 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:43 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:44 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:45 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:46 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:40:47 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:47 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: ip-172-31-53-225.ec2.internal
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 42845
     queue: default
     start time: 1554806436561
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1554806206610_0001/
     user: hadoop
19/04/09 10:40:48 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:49 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:50 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:51 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:52 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:54 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:55 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:56 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:57 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:58 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:40:59 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:00 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:01 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:02 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:03 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:04 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:04 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1554806436561
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1554806206610_0001/
     user: hadoop
19/04/09 10:41:05 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:06 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:07 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:08 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:09 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:10 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:11 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:12 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:13 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/04/09 10:41:14 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:14 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: ip-172-31-57-189.ec2.internal
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 45873
     queue: default
     start time: 1554806436561
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1554806206610_0001/
     user: hadoop
19/04/09 10:41:15 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:16 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:17 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:18 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:19 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:20 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:21 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:22 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:23 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:24 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:25 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:26 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:27 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/04/09 10:41:28 INFO Client: Application report for application_1554806206610_0001 (state: FINISHED)
19/04/09 10:41:28 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User application exited with status 1
     ApplicationMaster host: ip-172-31-57-189.ec2.internal
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 45873
     queue: default
     start time: 1554806436561
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-53-241.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1554806206610_0001/
     user: hadoop
19/04/09 10:41:28 ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User application exited with status 1
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1554806206610_0001 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1148)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1525)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
19/04/09 10:41:28 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/04/09 10:41:28 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-a8e941b7-f20f-46e5-8b2d-05c52785bd22
19/04/09 10:41:28 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-4475ef49-ca4e-4d5a-8570-0e66d88a4658
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

Anyone know where is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

finally i found the issue. The input data csv file's first line is an empty line.
it will cause a index out of range error in my program

Comment: I'm encountering the same exception when trying to import csv file. Can you share your sample file and let me know what caused the error? My file looks okay though.